# how to create a program so scanning a specific QR code will open whatever media player someone has on their device?

Tags: automation, qr-code, spotify

My goal is to create a program that can be ran by scanning a QR code that will then open up whichever music streaming service someone has on their device wither it be Spotify, apple music, etc.

More specifically say I wanted to open up to a particular artists page on a streaming server, right now I would have to create a QR code that would take me to a website and I would click what service I use and a link would take me there. I would like to bypass the whole process and have a program automatically detect what services I have installed on my phone, and open straight to it.

I feel like this has got to be pretty straight forward and doable. The only places I feel like you could run into trouble would be from and operating system trying to stop you for security reasons.

I'm completely inexperienced but would love a sense of direction to figure this out. Thanks!